# Prevent scrolling past a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a scrolling carousel, unlike other carousels this one doesn't jump from slide to slide but only allows the user to slowly move through them horizontally at a rate of 50px.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyLfz

Problem is when clicking next, once the number 6 box comes into full view the script should not allow the user to go any further, same for when the number 1 box is in full view and prev link is clicked, the user should not be allowed to scroll back anymore.

Right now I can't figure out how to do that.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
        <article class="pod">1</article>
        <article class="pod">2</article>
        <article class="pod">3</article>
        <article class="pod">4</article>
        <article class="pod">5</article>
        <article class="pod">6</article>   
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel { 
  position: relative; 
  border: 1px solid red; 
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel .slide { 
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
}
.carousel .slide .pod { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 18px white;
  color: #fff; 
  float: left; 
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
  $('.slide').animate({
    left: '-=50'
  });
});
$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  $('.slide').animate({
    left: '+=50'
  });
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you check the left position before animating?

Answer (score 0):

Your .carousel class need to have the same width at your .pod because you have the .carousel acting as a viewport.  Also, change 50px to 100px for your .animate().

Here is my version with the changes suggested:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hcewq

**EDIT**

Sorry.  I put the 50px offsets back.   I have boundary checks as before but the issue issue is the clicking versus the timing of the animation.  So, you need to check if your slider is going past its boundaries *and* have an animation flag check to see if the previous animation is complete or it will not get the latest offsets.

Here is the update: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJBzy

Comment: I need it to work the way I had it, that's what the designs suggests. Also your version still doesn't resolve the scrolling past issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some math to determine if you're at the end or not.

Here is your pen, forked: http://codepen.io/chrisrockwell/pen/dxqbp

The main part is in the `if` statement for your `next` action:

```
if (Math.abs(slideOffset.left) <= ($slide.width() - $('.carousel').width() - moveBy)) { 
  $slide.animate({
    left: next
  }); 
}
```

With this structure you are able to easily add `.pod`'s because, in your CSS, you can give `.slide` a ridiculously large width (10000em, for example) and it will still work.  You can also change the width of the `.pod`'s without having to modify anything but the CSS.  Finally, you can change the amount it moves by, should you ever need to, by changing just one variable.

To cover all scenarios, you would need to add in more checks, but this should get you started.

Comment: There would also be an issue with the click even happening before the animation ends.  There has to be a flag that is checked for the animation's complete (flag being set in the callback of .animate()).